# hibernate mapped and unmapped classes and mysql design

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am planning to design a new system with hibernate.
If I create a hibernate classes with mapping for example

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer userid;

    private String username;
    private String password;

    @OneToOne
    private Role userrole;

.....
}
```

add role class

```
@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String roleName;
...
}
```

In this case every time when i add the user to the database I have to get the role object from db and add to the user object and save it. If I define a mapping like this to other complicated design classes I have to fetch the related mapped classes from db. I feel like this an extra load to db. is their any way to it efficiently?

I have another plan to do like with out hibernate mapping

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer userid;

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Integer roleid;
 ....
}
```

In this case I can just add the id to user object and save it. But db classes wont get mapped. if i do it to all the classes I will have the db tables without mapping inside db
if i do it this to get the role name i have to create a another sql to get the role.

So in the first approach while saving object I have get the object and save and in the second approach we have to create two sql to get the two objects.
Is this good way to implement it?

From these two setup which is good and efficient and easy to use ?
Any discussion for recommended way please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this case every time when i add the user to the database I have to
>   get the role object from db and add to the user object and save it. If
>   I define a mapping like this to other complicated design classes I
>   have to fetch the related mapped classes from db. I feel like this an
>   extra load to db. is their any way to it efficiently?

Here, You did not load role object from DB. You should just create a Role instance and add that with User.

```
  Role r=new Role();
  r.setName("ROLE_NAME");

  user.setRole(r);
  r.setUser(user);
  session.saveOrUpdate(user);
  session.saveOrUpdate(r);
```

If you cascade the role with user, than you can reduce duplicate `saveOrUpdate()` operation.

> From these two setup which is good and efficient and easy to use ? Any
>   discussion for recommended way please ?

Generally, for JDBC authentication role and user table should be separate and mapped. So, first approach is  recommeded.

Comment: just create a role object with id and set it to user object is working. Thanks. And user has collection of addresses and made it lazy initialise to avoid load all the address when i fetch user object. But if I want to get the all the users with address how can u fetch it. it may be simple question because i am new to hibernate ?

Comment: If you define lazy initialization, then address will not load with user. As you call user.getAddress(), then address query will fire in database and load the address with user table.